# Write Spark Dataframe to DynamoDB using Python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I am trying to write a spark dataframe to a DDB table through a PySpark Glue job. I tried below options but keep getting the error "Failed to find data source".

```
redshift_df.write.format("io.aws.dynamodb").option("table", "accounts_payable_payee_info").save()
```

*Error: Failed to find data source: io.aws.dynamodb*

```
redshift_df.write.format("dynamodb").option("table", "accounts_payable_payee_info").save()
```

*Error: Failed to find data source: dynamodb*

Are there any external jars I need to use? Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: Plz tell which dynamodb lib and how you include the dependenct

Answer (score 0):

The best connector is the EMR DynamoDB connector:

https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector

It simplifies writing to DynamoDB.